# Change generated model name without deleting model django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

In django, by default, if you have a structure like this

```
app
├── migrations
└── models
      └ example
```

The generated name of your model will be `app_example` when executing the command `makemigrations`.
My problem is that I want to move my model from the directory app to the directory other_app which has the same structure.

```
other_app
├── migrations
└── models
    -> example will go here
```

At the same time, I want the generated name of my model to be `other_app_example` once I migrate without having to delete my table, as to avoid losing the data in it. The thing is, when you create a migration in django after changing a model of place, django delete the model in the migration directory of `app` and recreate it in another migration in `other_app`.

I know that I have to create a custom migration, but how can I achieve what I want to do ? All I found was RenameModel, but it doesn't change the name generated by django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it may not be the best one but it works !

Simply create an empty migration in `other_app` with the command `python manage.py makemigrations --empty other_app`.

In it, I added a runSql query where I renamed the table from app_example to other_app_example, like this :

```
    migrations.RunSQL(
        "ALTER TABLE app_example RENAME TO other_app_example;"
    ),
```

Before migrating, I just moved my `example` model to the model directory of `other_app`, then proceeded to do a `python manage.py migrate` and it worked fine !

The only downside to this method is that I did not manage to use other methods than raw sql with RunSQL, like RenameField or AlterField did not work for me. I then had to add every changes I wanted to do in raw sql.

Then, to fake the migrations generated by django that delete and create my model, as I couldn't use migrate --fake, I decided to set the managed parameter of my model to be set to false.